# ng-messages-include directive is not displaying messages

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I was hoping someone could tell me what I was doing wrong with the ngMessages directive. The code I am using is:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="error-messages">
    <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">This field is too short</div>
</script>


<div ng-controller="SomeController">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <form name="profileForm" ng-submit="model.submit()" novalidate>
              <div>
                  <label for="username">Your user name:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required placeholder="User name" ng-model="model.user.username">
                  <div class="help-block" ng-messages="profileForm.username.$error">
                      <div ng-messages-include="error-messages"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <button>submit</button>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I created a plunk here [ng-messages-include plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HKmRUl?p=info)

Been at this for hours.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngMessages` does not ship with angular by default. So, when you add `ng-messages` directive, angular doesn't compile it and nothing happens.

What you should do is add ng-messages to a script tag and add the module `ngMessages` in your app definition.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

var anApp = angular.module('anApp', ['ngMessages']);
```

See the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1CtamfeVCpggDApH9Enp?p=preview